# better performance count with mongodb 3.2

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

i have a compound index on (website and status)

i do this request on 5 millions documents :

`db.getCollection('comments').explain(true).find({website: ObjectId('5b2a0720a1d8cb4b4e0962a9'), status: {$in :["refused", "deleted"]} }).count()`

i have this result in 2,75 sec.

[image: result image]

Have you an idea to have a result in less 1 second ?

My Hardware, 2 Xeon 8 core, 96 Go Ram, Disk in Nvme (better of ssd)

Thanks,

Comment: It _feels_ that it should be faster. Maybe your hardware is not powerful enough?

Comment: why you don't use `count()` directly instead of `find().count()`!!!

Comment: in mongodb 3.2 count() execute in 2.9 sec and find().count() in 2.6 / 2.7 sec ^^, my hardware is Xeon with 96 Go Ram and Disk in Nvme (better of ssd)